# Option in diff to show differences in lines that include a certain word

Tags: diff

Is there any way using **diff** to show differences only in lines that include an specific word?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the option '-I *regexp*' to ignore the lines which match the specified regular expression. If you inverse the regex, you can ignore all lines NOT containing the word you're looking for.

See the [diff manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) for more info or [here](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/diff/diff.info.Specified_Folding.html) for a specific example.

Comment: How can I inverse the regex?, I looked around he man page, but I could figure out how to do that.